# How to host ArcGIS 9.3, 10.0 & 10.1 licenses on same server?

Tags: server, arcgis-license-manager

We have 3 license servers for ESRI products.

1. **Server 1**: 10.1 License Server
2. **Server 2**: 10.0 License Server
3. **Server 3**: 9.3 License Server

We are in the middle of a massive server migration/merge and would like to combine our license servers into one and store it on a single centrally-located machine. But we have some specific applications that require 9.3, a few that require 10.0, and our more common use-cases are migrating to 10.1 so we can't just upgrade the licenses. But keeping them on different servers won't work because we are losing some of our servers due to a reshuffle.

So, with 9.3 Concurrent use licenses being utilized, can we store those alongside 10.0 and 10.1 licenses on the same server without losing them?

Comment: What if this server fails is there any redundancy factored in? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/license-manager/10.1/index.html#//00790000000v000000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your 10.1 license server can host cocurrent use licenses for all 10.x and 9.x products.  We have a 10.1 license manager in production, our client environment is mix of 10 and 10.1 products.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/license-manager/10.1/index.html#/License_Manager_Basics/007900000003000000/